# Is numba automatically applied to functions which are called in other functions?

Tags: python, numba

Let's say I am doing stuff with large matrices:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit
def dostuff(mat):
    '''
    Do stuff with the matrix
    '''
    return np.exp(-1j*mat)
```

Doing this is actually slower than calling my custom exponential function cexp:

```
@jit
def dostuff_fast(mat):
    '''
    Do stuff with the matrix
    '''
    return cexp(-1j*mat)

@jit
def cexp(mat):
    return np.exp(mat)
```

Why so? Any ideas? Since creating custom functions and calling @jit before seems to be faster than using numpy functions I was wondering if there is a way to force jit to be applied to every function and operation which is called inside the function I want to optimise.

Comment: Numba can inline njitted functions, which is normally faster. (Your second approach will turn in your first) Can you provide a full example where you see this issue?

Comment: Well the code above basically is what's happening... you could just add mat = np.random.randn(30000,30000) for example

Comment: Can you give the timings you get? On my machine with `mat = np.random.randn(10000,10000) `, `dostuff` runs in 4.1s and `dostuff_fast` in 5.3s. Make sure you run it several times and average the timings (the first run can be significantly slower)